# Is it possible to configure Apache to be both a static web server and a load balancer on the same port?

Tags: apache-http-server, load-balancer

I am using Apache 2.4.7 on a Windows 2016 Server as a load balancer between a couple of Spring Boot REST applications using `<VirtualHost *:8000>` section. This is working fine.

However, I have also an Angular single page application and I want to host its files (HTML, CSS, JS, etc…) on the same Apache server. I need to use the same port number `8000`, since the Angular application is making the REST calls, otherwise I will get a CORS error.

My question is: How is it possible to configure Apache to be both a static web server and a load balancer on the same port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure about your specific setup and details, but in general what you are looking to do is setup and [Apache Reverse Proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html). You don’t need to configure a new port or anything like that. As the official Apache docs explain:

> In addition to being a "basic" web server, and providing static and dynamic content to end-users, Apache httpd (as well as most other web servers) can also act as a reverse proxy server, also-known-as a "gateway" server.
>
> In such scenarios, httpd itself does not generate or host the data, but rather the content is obtained by one or several backend servers, which normally have no direct connection to the external network. As httpd receives a request from a client, the request itself is *proxied* to one of these backend servers, which then handles the request, generates the content and then sends this content back to httpd, which then generates the actual HTTP response back to the client.

So in your case, the thing you need to know about Apache is you can configure paths and directories to behave in specific ways in Apache. So one URL can either be acted on for specific configs and behaviors or even ignored.

For more details on how an Apache Reverse Proxy can be configured, [check out this answer I posted on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/486112/100013).